# Ionic switch between tabs with parameters

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an app with tabs, where the first tab I show the latest post and an input search where a user can filter the results.

When user makes a search, I want to switch to the second tab, which will manage the search and display the results. I want to keep the first tab showing the latest post.

The code for switching to the second tab is:

```
    $scope.search_posts = function() {
        if ( !angular.isUndefined($scope.searchText) && $scope.searchText.length > 2 ) {
            $scope.searchText      = '';
            $scope.show_search_box = false;
            $ionicTabsDelegate.select($ionicTabsDelegate.selectedIndex() + 1);
        } else {
            $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'You must write at least 3 characters long.', noBackdrop: false, duration: 2000 });
        }
    }
```

...but I do not know how to send the 'searchText' as a parameter when switching.

**How can I accomplish this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `$rootScope` to store shared data:

```
$scope.search_posts = function() {
    if ( !angular.isUndefined($scope.searchText) && $scope.searchText.length > 2 ) {
        $rootScope.searchTextFromTabOne = $scope.searchText;
        $scope.searchText = '';
        $scope.show_search_box = false;
        $ionicTabsDelegate.select($ionicTabsDelegate.selectedIndex() + 1);
    } else {
        $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'You must write at least 3 characters long.', noBackdrop: false, duration: 2000 });
    }
}

//in tab two's controller
$scope.searchText = $rootScope.searchTextFromTabOne;
```

Comment: Hi, yes I used a factory to hold the data instead, a similar way than yours one and works fine. Thanks.